# C - char length more than 255 - SIGSEGV error

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault

I run this code - https://github.com/jesobreira/gammu-sms-tools/blob/master/gammu-long-sms.c
on my raspberry to send SMS.

If the SMS have more than 255 chars, it gives an error "SIGSEGV".

I think it is on line 61:

```
char *message_text = argv[2];
```

Is possible to have string in this variable longer than 255 chars?

Comment: Yes and the problem is unrelated to the line you posted.... And probably related to the next `unsigned char message_unicode[(sizeof(message_text) + 1) * 2];` line..

Comment: Don't *think*, by using a debugger to catch the crash you can *know* where the problem is and can start to figure out what might cause it.

Comment: And as a hint: Doing `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the *pointer*, and not whatever it might point to.

Comment: The linked code looks quite bad overall and probably shouldn't be used for any purpose...

Comment: I agree with @Lundin. I checked the [EncodeUnicode](https://github.com/gammu/gammu/blob/ed2fec4a382e7ac4b5dfc92f5b10811f76f4817e/libgammu/misc/coding/coding.c#L336) function, and it just doesn't work.

Comment: DO not post links to code.  Rather copy/paste the code directly into the question.

Comment: regarding: `char *message_text = argv[2];`  All this does is assign the pointer `message_text` with the address of the third parameter in `argv[]`